# XPath to the children as well as "text children"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

```
<li>
    <b>word</b>
    <i>type</i>
    <b>1.</b>
    "translation 1"
    <b>2.</b>
    "translation 2"           
</li>
```

I'm doing webscraping from an online dictionary, and the main dictionary part has roughly the above structure.

How exactly do I get all those children? With the usual selenium approach I see online, that is `list_elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*")` I only get the "proper" children, but not the textual ones (sorry if my word choice is off). Meaning I would like to have `len(children) == 6`, instead of `len(children) == 4`

I would like to get all children for further analysis

Comment: Do you want to get list of 6 string elements as output?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all children (including descendant) text nodes from `li` node you can try this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(<URL>)

li = driver.find_element('xpath', '//li')
nodes = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes", li)
text_nodes = []
for node in nodes:
    if not isinstance(node, WebElement):  # Extract text from direct child text nodes
        _text = node['textContent'].strip()
        if _text:  # Ignore all the empty text nodes
            text_nodes.append(_text)
    else:  # Extract text from WebElements like <b>, <i>... 
        text_nodes.append(node.text)

print(text_nodes)
```

Output:

```
['word', 'type', '1.', '"translation 1"', '2.', '"translation 2"']
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements `*`, `comment()`, `text()`, and `processing-instruction()` are all nodes.

To select all nodes:

```
.//node()
```

To ensure that it's only selecting `*` and `text()` you can add a predicate filter:

```
.//node()[self::* or self::text()]
```

However, the Selenium method is `find_element()` (and there is `find_elements()`) and they expect to locate elements and not `text()`. It seems that there isn't a more generic method to find nodes, so you may need to write some code to achieve what you want, such as JaSON answer.

Comment: Not sure whether it is selenium-specific, but I can only use your two suggestions with `find_element` and not `find_elements`. There I get `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression ".//node()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Selenium expert but I've read StackOverflow answers where apparently knowledgeable people have asserted that Selenium's XPath queries must return elements (so text nodes are not supported as a query result type), and I'm pretty sure that's correct.

So a query like like `//*` (return every element in the document) will work fine in Selenium, but `//text()` (return every text node in the document) won't, because although it's a valid XPath query, it returns text nodes rather than elements.

I suggest you consider using a different XPath API to execute your XPath queries, e.g. [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath), which doesn't have that limitation.